Why is the size of this subclass the same as the base class even though it adds a member variable?
In the following code, why is the size of Parent the same as the size of Child (even though Child adds a member variable)? Another weird behaviour: if I comment out the line where b is defined, the size of Child stays the same, but if I add another variable (int b, c;) then sizeof gives 24.
An explanation of why this happens would be greatly appreciated (:
#include <iostream>

class Parent {
    int a = 0;
public:
    virtual void foo() {}
};

class Child : public Parent {
    int b; // this line doesn't affect the output
};

int main() {
    std::cout << sizeof(Parent) << ", " << sizeof(Child);
    return 0;
}
// Output is : 16, 16

NB : this is my first time asking questions here so feel free to ask me to edit it if it is unclear or poorly formulated.

It is due to alignment and padding. Parent class has 4 bytes unused due to alignment requirement to have size equal 0 modulo 8. The Child class can use those 4 extra bytes for its purposes.

std::cout << alignof(Parent) << ", " << alignof(Child) << "\n"; may help.

Thank you all for your answers/comments, I think @Peter's answer explains it well : this is due to the 8 byte alignment required by the virtual function (on my system at least).
So interestingly, without the virtual function :
class Parent 
{
    int a = 0;
public:
    // virtual void foo() {}
};

The result of alignof(Parent) is 4, and so any single int variable will make a difference in the result of sizeof, but with the virtual function :
class Parent 
{
    int a = 0;
public:
    virtual void foo() {}
};

alignof(Parent) now gives 8, so it would take two more int variables to change the result of sizeof.

In fact you using your own words partially rewrote my answer.:)

@VladfromMoscow Yes you are absolutely correct, I just felt like your answer was lacking the clarification peter added so I decided to extend it here (which I apparently can't accept in the first 48 hours), but if you want to edit your answer I'll gladly accept it instead.

It is due to the presence of the virtual function foo:
virtual void foo() {}

The compiler generates a pointer to the table of virtual function addresses that it seems in your system is equal to 8 while sizeof( int ) is equal to 4. So due the allgnment of the address to 8 bytes of the parent class its size is equal to 16.
If you will remove the virtual function in the parent class or at least declare the data member a of the parent class with a type sizeof of which is equal to the sizeof of the pointer to the table of virtual function addresses then sizes of classes will be different
Here are two demonstration programs.
#include <iostream>

class Parent
{
    int a = 0;
public:
//    virtual void foo() {}
};

class Child : public Parent
{
    int b;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << sizeof( Parent ) << ", " << sizeof( Child ) << '\n';
}

The program output is
4, 8

And
#include <iostream>

class Parent
{
    long long int a = 0;
public:
    virtual void foo() {}
};

class Child : public Parent
{
    int b;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << sizeof( Parent ) << ", " << sizeof( Child ) << '\n';
}

The program output is
16, 24


Make up your mind. Is it due to (1) the virtual function or (2) the alignment of the parent class? If the alignment requirement is 16 what possible difference can the presence or absence of an 8-byte pointer make?

@user207421   It would, practically, often be a combination of those two factors.  A vtable isn't formally a member (in fact, the standard doesn't require an implementation to use a vtable at all) but, on most platforms, a vtable pointer will often have its own alignment requirement.

@user207421 I hope my answer is written enough clear.:)
